# Magento custom extension give 404 page when ckick on add new item

Tags: php, mysql, magento-1.9.1

Magento 1.9.1.0
I am new to magento. i am working on extensions. I created an extension that will store data in data. When i click on add new item it give 404 error. 'Edit Item' is working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on it and got the answer.

```
public function newAction()
       {
          $this->_forward('edit');
       }
```

In this function i changed `$this->_forward('testedit');` to `$this->_forward('edit');` and it worked.